# would deleting commit delete the changes in the object repo

Tags: git

what does deleting a commit in git really do? Would I loose some changes. It should not in reality because every commit is going to have the entire snapshot of working directory. That should not be problem??.

I was looking at reverting a merge. And I found everybody talking about re-merging the merge commit again would not take the change from the original merge.

**edit**

Here is the context..
https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/2w0qpb/redo_a_merge_after_reverting_it/

it talks about losing the 99 changes...what is about losing..it is a snapshot everytime...I guess the question then is, what is saved in the commit's and what happens when it plays it(in case of cherry pick or rebase)...

Would not the latest commit be enough.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "deleting a commit"? Could you show us the exact situation and commands you're referring to? Perhaps with a `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` of the relevant commits?

Comment: I have added the context and updated in the edit section

Answer (score 1):

A commit is a snapshot of the entire repository at a given time. It consists of :

- pointer to a tree object containing the state of the repo - other trees, blobs (files)
- meta data - who introduced the change, etc.
- pointer to a parent
- identifying info

This commit object is stored in .git/objects. I would strongly advise against modifying this directly.

git revert will introduce changes that would be the opposite of the changes of a given commit (in your case the very last, merge commit, i.e. HEAD). Now this is actually a new commit in its own right.
It sounds to me that this is not what you are after. Instead, it sounds like you would like to erase from existence a merge commit and then merge again.

You can do:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

This will bring back the HEAD pointer to the state before the merge. Any changes introduced by the original merge commit will still be in the working directory. To get rid of these you can do

```
git reset --hard
```

Now, the merge commit will still exist for a little while longer. You can retrieve a pointer to it if need be through walking the ref logs

```
git log -g
```

Eventually, this commit will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually *delete* a commit.  As in [Svetlomir Hristozkov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47064566/1256452), you can "reset it away" so that is not [*reachable*](http://think-like-a-git.net/) from the current branch tip.  If it is unreachable from all external references (including reflog references), `git gc` will generally throw it out at that point.

I find the whole thing more explainable in Mercurial, where you run `hg strip -r <rev>` to strip out revision `<rev>` *and all its descendants*.  You must do the same thing in Git, for the commit to become unreachable, because each descendant commit (child, grand-child, great-grand-child, and so on) encodes, as part of its [Merkle-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree)-forming hash ID, the hash ID of the commit you want to strip.  So you *must* discard all the descendants of the commit.  If you want to *keep* those descendants—which most people do—you must "graft" new copies of those snapshots and their metadata into a new chain of descendants that descend from the parent(s) of the commit(s) you want to "snip out".

The primary way to do this in Git is using `git filter-branch`.  The `git filter-branch` command simply copies *every* commit (or more precisely, every commit in some restricted subset of the repository based on reference names and other restrictors you supply as arguments).  To make the copy, it:

1. extracts the original;
2. applies each filter in order; and
3. commits the result.

If the new commit is bit-for-bit identical to the original commit, they wind up with the same hash ID.  If any bit(s) change, the new commit has a new, different hash ID, and that new ID acts as the input to the parent(s) of subsequent children.

As `git filter-branch` moves from commit to commit, it builds a map of "old hash ID" to "nearest appropriate new hash ID".  This map is how children of the to-be-snipped, or otherwise modified, commit(s) can be re-parented during the copy operation.

The `--parent-filter` allows you to make an arbitrary change to parent hash IDs, and the `--commit-filter` can deliberately *skip* a commit.  For details, see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html).  However, note that `git filter-branch` obeys replacement objects created by `git replace`, so you can use `git replace` to splice out some commit(s), then if desired, use a no-op `git filter-branch` to copy everything while obeying the replacement, effectively forming a new commit graph that lacks the spliced-out commits.

Once you do this and instruct `git filter-branch` to update the appropriate external references (branch names and tags, mostly), you have a new repository that omits the commit(s) you want omitted.

There is a flaw in `git filter-branch` in that it does not do anything useful with `git notes`.  The `git rebase` command by default will copy notes.  For some limited cases, an interactive rebase, which copies commits, can be used to strip out commits—but since the *goal* is different, `git rebase` uses `git cherry-pick` to make the copies, and this does not behave the way `git filter-branch` behaves.